# Css float inner div with overflow

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this html: http://jsfiddle.net/mW2Jh/3/

```
<div style="width:200px;overflow-x:auto">
    <table style="background-color:yellow" width="400px" height="200px">
        <tr>
            <td>first column</td>
            <td>second column</td>
            <td style="width:20px;">BTN</td>
        </tr>
```

I want that BTN column is "attached" to the right of container div. If i scroll horizontally i want that the button are always on the right. If i scroll vertically i want that the buttons scroll with the table rows.
The solution may works on all browser.

The old code was using css expression (work only in IE <= 8)

Thanks and sorry for my english

Comment: can you explain again.haha its too vague. :)

Comment: vague yeah.. this? http://jsfiddle.net/mW2Jh/5/

Comment: you want the 3rd column to be fixed .. always visible?

Comment: if you need your buttons to be always visible when scrolling horizontally (but still scroll vertically), this a solution using jQuery http://jsfiddle.net/mW2Jh/26/

Comment: Thank you cdMinix, this is the solution!

Comment: Check if [this](http://jsfiddle.net/mW2Jh/35/) helps you.

Answer (score 1):

With JQuery, use the scrollLeft() property of the document! This would work

```
$(window).scroll(function(event) {
   $(id).css("margin-left", 400-$(document).scrollLeft());
});
```

See also

http://jsfiddle.net/zhQkq/9/